# Removing headers from jquery text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I need to get the text from a div with an id of mycenter, but I do not want the header text i.e.
`<h2>This is my Title</h2>.` I only want the text after the header. Additionally, sometimes the div does not contain any header.

I tried:

```
var pageText = $('#mycenter').text();
```

This correctly returns the text in the div, but this includes "This is My Title".

Any clue on how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`contents()` function](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to fetch all child nodes *including* text nodes.  Then filter the set however you like, and finally extract the text from the remaining set.

Given a document fragment like this:

```
<div id="mycenter">
    some text 1
    <h2>The header</h2>
    some text 2
    <div>other stuff</div>
    <h1>another header</h1>
</div>
```

**Option #1** : Return only the text that is an immediate child of `#mycenter`, thus excluding the text of *all* child elements (not just h* elements):

```
$('#mycenter').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();
```

Gives us:

```
some text 1
some text 2
```

**Option #2** : Return *all* descendent text, except the contents of header (H1-H6) elements that are immediate children of #mycenter:

```
$('#mycenter').contents().not('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').text();
```

Gives us:

```
some text 1
some text 2
other stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution can be

```
var pageClone = $('#mycenter').clone();
pageClone.find(':header').remove();
var pageText = pageClone.text();
pageClone.remove();
```

This very well may be inefficient but it will likely serve your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Hej Regis

http://jsfiddle.net/buyms/

So what you can do is clone the div and remove the tags in it you dont want
like this

```
var text = $("div").clone()
   .find("h2").remove().end()
   .text();


alert(text);
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#mycenter *").not("h2").text()
```

OR

```
$("div :not('h2')").text() // see example below and this will make sense.
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Wer58/

Comment: `$("div :not('h2')").text()` would probably be broken if there's no <p> in the html.

Answer (score 0):

I went the regular expression route, but as you're using jQuery anyway I'd go with @Lee's  solution.

```
var pageText = $('#mycenter').html().replace(/\<h2\>.*\<\/h2\>/, '')
        .replace( /^\s+|\s+$/g, '' );
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jkeyes/RpFjc/